# Super simple templated memory pool in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a small program where I have a background thread that plays sound, so it needs to run really fast, but it also needs to do a small amount of memory management. I didn't want to use normal new and delete in a time critical area, so I threw this together, but set it up so I could reuse it elsewhere.

```
template <typename T, unsigned int capacity>
class MemoryPool
{
public:
    MemoryPool()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            myUnusedMemory[i] = &myMemory[i];
        }
    }

    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        return myUnusedMemory[myUnusedIndex--];
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr)
    {
        myUnusedMemory[++myUnusedIndex] = (T*)ptr;
    }

private:
    static int myUnusedIndex;
    static T myMemory[capacity];
    static T* myUnusedMemory[capacity];
};

template <typename T, unsigned int capacity> int MemoryPool<T, capacity>::myUnusedIndex = capacity-1;
template <typename T, unsigned int capacity> T MemoryPool<T, capacity>::myMemory[capacity];
template <typename T, unsigned int capacity> T* MemoryPool<T, capacity>::myUnusedMemory[capacity];
```

The intended usage is something like this:

```
struct Sound : public ag::util::MemoryPool<Sound, 100>
{
    // ...
};
```

Now when calling `new Sound()` I get one from my memory pool, which should be super fast. The only things that I can think of that could be improved are making `operator new` throw an exception when at capacity. I think I might be able to do away with `typename T`. The only  reason it's needed is so that `myMemory` knows the size of its elements, but I feel like there's another solution here.

Answer (score 8):

This currently will not work.

As every-time you create an object derived from `MemoryPool` you re-initialize the `myUnusedMemory` structure thus potentially messing up your management.

```
struct Game : public ag::util::MemoryPool<Game, 2>  {};


int main()
{
    Game* p1  = new Game;
    Game* p2  = new Game;
    delete p1;
    delete p2;

    // myUnusedMemory now set like this:
    // myUnusedMemory[0] = &myMemory[1];
    // myUnusedMemory[1] = &myMemory[0];

    // Now when we create the next one it resets the array:

    Game* p3  = new Game;
    // myUnusedMemory now set like this: (because the constructor reset the array)
    // myUnusedMemory[0] = &myMemory[0];
    // myUnusedMemory[1] = &myMemory[1];

    Game* p4  = new Game;  // Now p3 and p4 point at the same memory location
}
```

This line:

```
static T myMemory[capacity];
```

Is also not good as you are actually initializing the objects. Thus, when you are calling `new` your `new operator` is returning a pointer to an already initialized object . The constructor will then be re-called. Thus overriding the original content without the destructor being called (thus leaking any memory that should have been deleted).

I suppose you could call the destructor inside the `new operator` but that seems wasteful (and may be expensive) and sort of counter intuitive. So you want to use uninitialized memory for your pool.
You could do this:

```
static char myMemory[capacity * sizeof(T)];
```

But unfortunately this is not guaranteed to be correctly aligned.
If you dynamically allocate the memory then it will be fine. Use `std::vector` and it will be dynamically allocated and safe.

```
static std::vector<char>  myMemory(capacity * sizeof(T));
```

Comment: Oh duh, you're right wrt the constructor. Thank you much.

Comment: `boost` and `c++11` can help with alignment.

Comment: @user1095108: C++03 works well on alignment. Just use a `std::vector<>`

Comment: @LokiAstari Not, if you _don't_ want to allocate from the heap.

Comment: @user1095108: (1) don't use the term heap in C++ its not accurate. You mean "dynamic" memory. (2) It is a bad idea to use "automatic" memory as there is a size limit relative to the [maximum size of the stack frame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/216731/14065) which is very variable and compiler/hardware dependant.